# DB Error: 26 "file is not a database" FMDB with SQLCipher

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb, sqlcipher

Hello I am trying to open password protected database file. I ma using **FMDB/SQLCipher**. I am getting error `file is not a database`.

```
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &pStmt, 0);
if (SQLITE_OK != rc) {
            if (_logsErrors) {
                NSLog(@"DB Error: %d \"%@\"", [self lastErrorCode], [self lastErrorMessage]);
            }
}

DB Error: 26 "file is not a database.
```

I had added database at current place. My pod looks like

```
target 'FMDBDemo' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'FMDB/SQLCipher'   # FMDB with SQLCipher

  post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          if target.name == "FMDB"
              config_path = target.build_configurations[0].base_configuration_reference.real_path
              File.open(config_path, "a") {|file| file.write("HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = SQLCipher")}
          end
      end
  end

end
```

Comment: How was the database initially encrypted? What version of SQLCipher was used to encrypt the database? The current FMDB/SQLCipher subspec is using SQLCipher version 4.x so if your database was originally created using an older version of SQLCipher you'll need to use one of the options listed here: https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/upgrading-to-sqlcipher-4/3283 to upgrade. As a side note, the post install hook should no longer be necessary since this PR was merged in: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/pull/672

Comment: @R4N thanks your comments help me

Comment: @SShah hello, buddy. I've run into the same error. Did you find an eventual solution to this?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I was checking old encrypted database.. So first check the encrypted database is encrypted with SQLCipher version 4.x..